# Error al configurar Apache Tomcat en Eclipse JEE

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

Estoy tratando de agregar un nuevo servidor en **Window > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environments**

Y selecciono la opción **Apache Tomcat v8.0**, pero la versión de Apache Tomcat que tengo es la **8.5.11**  por lo tanto obtengo el siguiente error:

```
The Apache Tomcat installation at this directory is version 8.5.11.  A Tomcat 8.0 installation is expected.
```

Debo descargar una versión mas antigua de Tomcat o hay alguna forma de agregar **Tomcat 8.5.11** en eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que he podido ver es un problema de Tomcat. Intenta modificar las el fichero ServerInfo.properties que se encuentra en **\lib\catalina.jar** en la carpeta de instalación de Tomcat y añade las siguientes líneas:

```
server.info=Apache Tomcat/8.0.0
server.number=8.5.5.0
server.built=Aug 31 2016 19:51:16 UTC
```

Un saludo :)

Answer (score 0):

Hay que utilizar  **Eclipse JEE neon**, ya que esté incluye soporte para **TomCat** hasta su versión **9.0**, de esta forma se podrá agregar el servidor sin problemas.